# C language pattern decoder

Tags: c, algorithm, decoding

I am trying to develop a pattern decoder using a C language program. The pattern will be like for example:

```
5 8
1
2
4 
3 
1
1 3 2 1 0 1 2 1
```

The first row indicates the number of rows and columns. The next several rows list the count of painted squares in each row, and the final row has space-separated counts of painted squares per column.

It is a 5x8 board with painted and unpainted dots or squares. The pattern might be represented in a .txt file.
The same representation can be seen on the attached image.
The expected output is as follows, where represented by a '-' are the unpainted dots or squares and by '#' the painted ones.

Expected pattern

```
-#------
-##-----
####----
-----###
------#-
```

Program output

```
#-------
##------
####----
###---#-
####-###
```

I tried writing some code but it is not displaying or printing correctly and I have tried debugging with no success.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 8

int main() {
    int row_counts[] = {1, 2, 4, 3, 1};
    int col_counts[] = {1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1};

    char board[ROWS][COLS];
    int i, j;

    // Initialize the board with unpainted dots
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }

    // Paint the dots based on row and column counts
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < row_counts[i]; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }
    
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        for (i = ROWS - 1; i >= ROWS - col_counts[j]; i--) {
            board[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }

    // Print the decoded pattern
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            printf("%c", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll first have to think what kind of algorithm you want to implement? Have you tried doing this on a piece of paper? How will you approach it then?

Comment: @please help, I suspect that for a given input, there may exist multiple decoded patterns or perhaps even no possible solution.

Comment: This is known as a [nonogram puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram). Solving a nonogram is an NP-complete problem, which is to say that it's not easy, in general. However, given that you have only one number per row, and one number per column, a brute force algorithm may actually work for a small puzzle.

Comment: The post contained three versions of the same pattern. I replaced them with the original text version, plus the output of my compilation. However, the post does not fully explain the meaning of the input file. Most is clear, but not the last line which perhaps relates to the positioning. My guess is it gives the number of glyphs needed in each column.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, the last line has the 8 column counts.

Comment: My guess is you could use a recursive algorithm, and as mentioned for this size, brute force. I also guess this is an online 'challenge' question, since the solution can hardly be of general use. Good luck!

Comment: @user3386109 in fact if there is only one total count per row/column, then it is no longer NP-complete.

Comment: The OP doesn't say that the painted squares have to be adjacent in each row and column. If they don't, then this can be solved greedily, though there will usually be many solutions.

Comment: This is a homework assignment for a class or is an online judge/contest problem or other exercise. Which class is it? The context of the problem is a clue about the method intended to be used to solve it. If it is a graph theory class or related, you should probably be using the max-flow approach in [Matt Timmermans’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76477149/298225). I suppose it is possible you are supposed to use a brute-force approach in some lower level programming class.

Comment: My brute-force solver indicates that there are actually multiple solutions for the same number-pattern.  A unique answer is not at all guaranteed.

Comment: @abelenky The expected output shown in the question is the unique answer per the rules of a nonogram.

Comment: @user3386109 Why do you think this is a nonogram?

Answer (score 3):

You can transform this problem into a [max-flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) by constructing a flow network as follows:

1. There is a single source vertex
2. There is a vertex for each row, and an edge from the source to each row with capacity equal to the row count.
3. There is a vertex for each column, and an edge from each row to each column, with capacity 1. These edges correspond to the cells in your matrix.
4. There is a single sink vertex, and an edge from each column vertex to the sink, with capacity equal to the column count.

Now you can find a maximum flow from source to sink, using, for example, the [Edmonds-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).  In your matrix, then, paint every square if its row->column edge is used in the flow.  If your flow doesn't meet all the row and column limits, then there is no solution.

Comment: I don't see how this guarantees that the painted squares in a row (or column) are adjacent.

Comment: @user3386109: The question does not state that as a requirement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, but the actual source does state that as a requirement. I've seen this question before, with the exact same expected output pattern, and the OP of that question actually explained the requirements. The expected output shown in this question is the one and only acceptable output.

Comment: @user3386109: What “actual source”? The question does not cite a source.

Comment: @user3386109 I answered the question that was asked, not one you think that the OP really meant.

Comment: @MattTimmermans When a question provides an expected output, the answer to the question must generate that output, not one you think that the OP really meant.

Comment: It's a possible output...

Comment: [It's a nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test). There's only one output, and that's the one given in the question.